# random.randint generating incorrect numbers

Tags: python, random

So i am making a quick dice roller (for D&D) and when I try to roll dice it only generates numbers from 1 to 4!

```
import random


def d4():
    x = (random.randint(1,4))
    print(x)

def d6():
    x = (random.randint(1,6))
    print(x)

def d8():
    x = (random.randint(1,8))
    print(x)

def d10():
    x = (random.randint(1,10))
    print(x)

def d12():
    x = (random.randint(1,12))
    print(x)

def d20():
    x = (random.randint(1,20))
    print(x)

def d100():
    x = (random.randint(1,100))
    print(x)


choice = input("What dice will you roll: ")


if choice == "d4" or "4":
    d4()
elif choice == "d6" or "6":
    d6()
elif choice == "d8" or "8":
    d8()
elif choice == "d10" or "10":
    d10()
elif choice == "d12" or "12":
    d12()
elif choice == "d20" or "20":
    d20()
elif choice == "d100" or "100":
    d100()
else:
    print(random.randint(1,20))
```

For example when I put my input as d100 I can only get 1,2,3, or 4!
what on earth is going on?!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are not correct, they should be like this:

```
if choice == "d4" or choice == "4":
    d4()
```

The way you did it makes "4" evaluate to True, so the if always enters to the first statement, which is for D4.